# Reading IP address from a file in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm trying to read a couple thousand IPv4 addresses from a text file and put them into C++ string arrays. Here is what I have so far

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string fileName1,fileName2;
    fileName1="file1Large.txt";
    ifstream inData;
    inData.open(fileName1);
    string file1[10000];
    int i=0;
    while(inData)
    {
        inData>>file1[i];
        i++;
    }
    cout<<"File1: "<<endl;
    for(int z=0; z <= 10000; z++)
    {
        cout<<file1[z];
    }
    inData.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

When I run this I am getting an unhandled exception and I'm not sure what is wrong.I have used mostly Java and not much C++ so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: One thing : use z < 10000 otherwise you will read beyond the array end. Indexes are zero based. Currently you have z <= 10000

Comment: Does your file have exactly 10000 elements in it? If not, change the condition in the `for` loop to be `z < i` since `i` counted the number of elements it read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your array maybe going out of bounds.

Try:

```
while(i < 10000 && inData >> file1[i])
    {
        i++;
    }
```

Also, this certainly is a problem:

```
for(int z=0; z < i; z++) // remove = and change 10000 to i
    {
        cout<<file1[z];
    }
```

**EDIT: As Dave Rager pointed out, the maximum value of iterations should be i and not 10000.**

Answer (score 2):

If you can use standard containers and algorithms, the following solution would read all the IPs into a vector of strings (assuming the input is separated by newlines):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
// 
// compile as:
// 
// g++ example.cpp -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra
//
// I used GCC 4.8.1 on OS X 10.7.4
// 
int main() {
  // this container will grow automatically; it saves you the hassle
  // of managing the underlying buffer
  std::vector<std::string> data;

  { // this is a new scope for the file stream; it will close
    // automatically when it leaves this scope (you don't have to call
    // fp.close())
    std::ifstream fp("ips.txt");
    // this will do literally as it says: "for as long as you can
    // extract an string from the file, back-insert it into the vector
    // of strings called 'data'"
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(fp),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter<std::vector<std::string>>(data));
  } // this is the end of the scope mentioned above; `fp` does not
    // exist beyond here

  // this simply prints the data as you read it; it says "copy all the
  // contents of data to the output stream called "cout" separating
  // every entry with a new line"
  std::copy(data.begin(),
            data.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));  
}
```

Sample file:

```
$ cat > ips.txt
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
9.10.11.12
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./a.out 
1.2.3.4
5.6.7.8
9.10.11.12
```

*Notice that to use the standard containers and algorithms as I present in the example, your compiler needs to support the C++11 Standard*